# Redirecting percentage of traffic

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, ab-testing

I'm trying to redirect 10% of my users to a beta site we are testing. I am using the Codeigniter framework and I have added the following to the routes.php file:

```
$absplit = 0.1;
if((mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax() - 1) / mt_getrandmax() < $absplit))
{
    header('location: '.str_replace($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST],"x.example.com","http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"),true,302);
    exit;
}
```

However, I'm noticing that it's redirecting nearly 40% of the traffic and seems to redirect in chunks of time (e.g. all users for 10 minutes go to one site). Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: for a better spread use the time in secounds, redirect hits on  1,6,12 .. secounds

Comment: Create a table with one field of type int. In your main controllers index function, increment that value by 1. Then check it's value, if it is >= to 10 then use a redirect() call and set the database value back to 0.

Comment: if i hit the same URL twice there are chances that i land on different versions of site. better use `session` so that a particular user is on either of site and not both.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with one field of type int. 
In your main controllers index function, increment that value by 1. 
Then check it's value, if it is >= to 10 then use a redirect() call and set the database value back to 0.

Comment: This actually is not ideal from a testing perspective as it invalidates results by breaking the assumption of random selection of groups. In order to have a valid A/B test you must use random assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the backend code you can just write a JavaScript that does the redirect. For example,

```js
if (Math.random() <= 0.1) {
  location.href = '/url-to-redirect-to';
}
```

If you want the users to have consistent experience. You can save some value to the cookie which will indicate that they have or have not to be redirected.

```js
var cookieValue = cookie.get(key);

if (cookieValue === 'redirect' || !cookieValue && Math.random() <= 0.1) {
  cookie.set(key, 'redirect');
  location.href = '/url-to-redirect-to';
} else {
  cookie.set(key, 'no-redirect');
}
```

This is how essentialy front-end A/B testing works. [Here](https://github.com/zkochan/abo/blob/master/lib/select-expt.js) you can see a more complex example of traffic allocation between many experiments with different percentages of traffic and assignment conditions.

However, in your case a simple if will be enough.